# Why is laravel middleware is returning null for a response?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am saving all of the log interaction in my laravel middleware. I am getting all the request info but the response is returning null. Here is the code below in middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){   
    $response= $next($request);

    $logroute = new model_logroute();
    $logroute->uri=$request->getUri(); // working
    $logroute->request_body=json_encode($request->all()); //working
    $logroute->response=json_encode($response->getContent()); // returning null
    $logroute->save();

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Response has not been generated yet when the middleware is trying to access it.

Comment: @kampit that might be the case, how can I get the response please in a different way?

Comment: Try add if condition `if ($response->content()) { $logroute->response... }`

Answer (score 0):

use [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#terminable-middleware)

> Sometimes a middleware may need to do some work after the HTTP
> response has been sent to the browser. If you define a terminate
> method on your middleware and your web server is using FastCGI, the
> terminate method will automatically be called after the response is
> sent to the browser:
>
> The terminate method should receive both the request and the response.
> Once you have defined a terminable middleware, you should add it to
> the list of routes or global middleware in the app/Http/Kernel.php
> file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TerminatingMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Handle tasks after the response has been sent to the browser.
     */
    public function terminate(Request $request, Response $response): void
    {
        $logroute = new model_logroute();
        $logroute->uri=$request->getUri(); // working
        $logroute->request_body=json_encode($request->all()); //working
        $logroute->response=json_encode($response->getContent()); // returning null
        $logroute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still the same. The response content is still empty. The response as a whole is {"headers":{},"original":null,"exception":null}

Comment: @Aman .I have tested now in laravel 10 .It receives response and request

Comment: @Aman try clearing cache or running optimize:clear command and try to print before inserting into database like  info([
            "request"=>json_encode($request->all()),
            "response" =>json_encode($response->getContent())
        ]);

Comment: I finally understand the problem. It does work without TerminatingMiddleware. The issue from my side was I ECHO the output/json instead of RETURN the output/json. It should be 
RETURN JSON instead of ECHO json